# how can I point to a specific RecyclerView onClick view (Android Java)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-button

I have three `RecyclerViews` in an activity, also having three buttons on top of the activity.

I want to go to a specific RecyclerView on `onClick` of a respective `button` on top of an activity. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Use TabLayout and ViewPager

Comment: i have no tabs in my activity then how can we handle onclick of button to third recyclerView of my acitivity ???

Comment: are you using `nestedscrolview` to display all three `recyclerview`?

Comment: simple one ScrollView and inside that Scrollview I have these RecyclerViews with their respective id's

Answer (score 0):

Change `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`. You have to calculate your desired scroll position on `x` or `y` axis and use `NestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo()`.